# Set persistence strategy to "localTempSwap" in EHCache 3.x

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

In EHCache 3.1.3 The 2.x API to set the persistence strategy is missing, for instance the enum `net.sf.ehcache.config.PersistenceConfiguration.Strategy` is no longer in the lib.

I've read the docs (for version 3.1). but I couldn't find anything about how to configure the persistence strategy, so I suppose that in version 3.x is a different concept or maybe the feature has been removed, but It sounds a bit odd.

Can anyone tell me how can I to configure the EHCache 3.1.x to manage the persistence like `Strategy.LOCALTEMPSWAP` ? If It's not possible, Is there any alternative or workaround ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When configuring the disk tier in Ehcache 3.x there is a boolean value that indicates persistence:

- `true`: data will be preserved between JVM restarts if the `CacheManager` or `UserManagedCache` has been shut down properly using one of the `close` methods,
- `false`: data will not be preserved between JVM restarts although the disk is used during cache operations. Note that this is the default.

Usage depends on where your configuration is sourced from:

- In Java use `ResourcePoolsBuilder.disk(long size, MemoryUnit unit, boolean persistent)` with the boolean as defined above,
- In XML use `<ehcache:disk unit="GB" persistent="true">100</ehcache:disk>` with the boolean flag again as defined above.

So in order to achieve the equivalent of `Strategy.LOCALTEMPSWAP` in `2.x` you just can work with the default.

Note that as of `3.1.3` you can use a system property in the XML to configure the data folder location as in `${java.tmp.dir}`.

Comment: Could you please how did you inject the xml in the jsr implementation? Also a screenshot of your xml

Comment: This seems like a valid topic for a question on its own. Otherwise, have a look at [documentation](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.3/107.html#getting-jsr-107-caches-configured-through-ehcache-xml).

Comment: so if my client application terminates abruptly `killl -9` or OOM without calling `close` method it will loose all persisted data upon next restart ?